# Why isn't my hamburger navigation menu showing up?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet/styles.css"/>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/929330f5ee.js"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="nav-branding">MYBRAND</a>
        <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hamburger">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap');

*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    background-color: #E50914;

}


li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    color: white;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
    min-height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 24px;

}

.nav-menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 25px;
}

.nav-link{
    transition: 0.1s ease;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: rgb(73, 0, 0);
}

.hamburger{
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}



@media (max-width:800px){
    
   .hamburger{
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: x-large;
      }
    
   .nav-menu{
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
        top: 70px;
        gap: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #262626;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
    
   .nav-item{
        margin: 16px 0;
      }
    
   .nav-menu.active{
        left: 0;
      }
    }
```

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
})

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hamburger.classList.remove("active");
  navMenu.classList.remove("active");
}))
```

hi, I am trying to convert a navbar into a hamburger menu for mobile screens, but it seems like my hamburger icon shows up but the navigation menu doesn't...

I have tried everything I have copied the code from a youtube video. The code was working perfectly fine on the video but It seems like its not working for me.

I have just started coding and I'm learning css and html. I have just started learning JS.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. The menu shows up after clicking the icon: https://jsfiddle.net/qjrc4ywL/

Comment: I can see your code working on JSFiddle, but unfortunately, it does not work on my laptops or any other platform. Do you have any idea why would that be?

Comment: It's hard to help without a [mre] that can be run directly to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the color for the fa solid element

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: #ffffff"></i>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey thank you for the reply! But unfortunately my problem is not the hamburger icon showing, but the navigation bar elements ( ul, li ) does not show when I click on my hamburger icon :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried copy pasting the source code you provided and it works for me. That is, the navbar collapses into a hamburger when the screen is smaller than the specified max-width (800px) and expands back to normal otherwise. You can change the max-width value in the media query to something less (e.g., 640px) if you want it to expand for screens narrower than 800px.

Comment: yes but the problem is I still have my navigation bar, and what I'm trying to do is to show my navbar when clicked on the hamburger menu :(